# Difference between Quantile Regression and Endogenous Stratification

Tags: econometrics, regression, applied-econometrics, experimental-economics, heterogeneity

I have a question that stems from an ongoing experiment I'm conducting, focusing on treatment heterogeneity.

Initially, my approach involved considering a beyond-mean analysis utilizing quantile regressions. However, delving into more recent literature, I stumbled upon an alternative method for assessing the heterogeneity of effects, named "endogenous stratification" by Abadie (2018). For reference, the complete citation is provided below:

Abadie, A., Chingos, M. M., & West, M. R. (2018). Endogenous stratification in randomized experiments. Review of Economics and Statistics, 100(4), 567-580.

I want to understand the differences between these two methods. While I recognize they may not be directly comparable, I'm looking for an explanation of in what context one might be more beneficial or useful than the other.

Thank you very much for your assistance.